# Three-body problem

Tags: c++

I wrote the following program to solve the three body problem (Sun, Earth, Jupiter), initializing the system such that the total angular momentum is 0. The result of the simulation is really bad (and the Sun tend to infinity). I looked at the code for more than an hour trying to find the problem. Does anybody see what is wrong with my program?

Thank you very much.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include <fstream>
using std::ofstream;

#include <cmath>
using std::sqrt;

int main()
{
    double time(0), dt(0.05);

    double G(1.9838e-29);

    double m1(6e24), m2(1.9e27), ms(1.99e30);

    double x1(1), y1(0), x2(5.2), y2(0), xs(0), ys(0);

    double T1(1), T2(11.8618);

    double vx1(0),vy1(2*M_PI*x1/T1), vx2(0), vy2(2*M_PI*x2/T2);

    double Rx( (m1*x1+m2*x2+ms*xs)/(m1+m2+ms) ), Ry( (m1*y1+m2*y2+ms*ys)/(m1+m2+ms) );

    x1 = x1 - Rx;
    x2 = x2 - Rx;
    xs = xs - Rx;
    y1 = y1 - Ry;
    y2 = y2 - Ry;
    ys = ys - Ry;

    double Lx1(x1*m1*vx1), Lx2(x2*m2*vx2);

    double vxs(0), vys( -(Lx1+Lx2)/(ms*xs) );

    double r12(0), r1s(0), r2s(0);

    ofstream output("TB_jupiter-earth.dat");

    output << time << ' ' << x1 << ' ' << y1 << ' ' << x2 << ' ' << y2 << ' ' << xs << ' ' << ys <<endl;

    while(time < 12)
    {
        r12 = sqrt( (x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2) );
        r1s = sqrt( (x1-xs)*(x1-xs) + (y1-ys)*(y1-ys) );
        r2s = sqrt( (x2-xs)*(x2-xs) + (y2-ys)*(y2-ys) );

        vx1 = vx1 - G*ms*dt*(x1-xs)/(r1s*r1s*r1s) - G*m2*(x1-x2)*dt/(r12*r12*r12);
        vy1 = vy1 - G*ms*dt*(y1-ys)/(r1s*r1s*r1s) - G*m2*(y1-y2)*dt/(r12*r12*r12);

        vx2 = vx2 - G*ms*dt*x2/(r2s*r2s*r2s) - G*m1*(x2-x1)*dt/(r12*r12*r12);
        vy2 = vy2 - G*ms*dt*y2/(r2s*r2s*r2s) - G*m1*(y2-y1)*dt/(r12*r12*r12);

        vxs = vxs - G*m1*(xs-x1)*dt*(r1s*r1s*r1s) - G*m2*(xs-x2)*dt*(r2s*r2s*r2s);
        vys = vys - G*m1*(ys-y1)*dt*(r1s*r1s*r1s) - G*m2*(ys-y2)*dt*(r2s*r2s*r2s);


        x1 = x1 + vx1*dt;
        y1 = y1 + vy1*dt;

        x2 = x2 + vx2*dt;
        y2 = y2 + vy2*dt;

        xs = xs + vxs*dt;
        ys = ys + vys*dt;

        time += dt;

        output << time << ' ' << x1 << ' ' << y1 << ' ' << x2 << ' ' << y2 << ' ' << xs << ' ' << ys <<endl;
    }

    output.close();

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

The correction of the first answer were good but now I changed the calculations of the angula momentum (they were wrong) and the program doesn't work properly anymore. The code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include <fstream>
using std::ofstream;

#include <cmath>
using std::sqrt;

int main()
{
    double time(0), dt(0.005);

    double G(1.9838e-29);

    double m1(6e24), m2(500*1.9e27), ms(1.99e30);

    double x1(1), y1(0), x2(5.2), y2(0), xs(0), ys(0);

    double T1(1), T2(11.8618);

    double vx1(0),vy1(2*M_PI*x1/T1), vx2(0), vy2(2*M_PI*x2/T2);

    double Rx( (m1*x1+m2*x2+ms*xs)/(m1+m2+ms) ), Ry( (m1*y1+m2*y2+ms*ys)/(m1+m2+ms) );

    x1 = x1 - Rx;
    x2 = x2 - Rx;
    xs = xs - Rx;
    y1 = y1 - Ry;
    y2 = y2 - Ry;
    ys = ys - Ry;

    double Ly1(x1*m1*vy1), Ly2(x2*m2*vy2);

    double vxs(0), vys( -(Ly1+Ly2)/(ms*xs) );

    double r12(0), r1s(0), r2s(0);

    ofstream output("TB_jupiter-earth.dat");

    output << time << ' ' << x1 << ' ' << y1 << ' ' << x2 << ' ' << y2 << ' ' << xs << ' ' << ys <<endl;

    cout << x1 << ' ' << y1 << ' '<< vx1 << ' ' << vy1 << endl;
    cout << x2 << ' ' << y2 << ' '<< vx2 << ' ' << vy2 << endl;
    cout << xs << ' ' << ys << ' '<< vxs << ' ' << vys << endl;

    while(time < 4)
    {
        r12 = sqrt( (x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2) );
        r1s = sqrt( (x1-xs)*(x1-xs) + (y1-ys)*(y1-ys) );
        r2s = sqrt( (x2-xs)*(x2-xs) + (y2-ys)*(y2-ys) );

        vx1 = vx1 - G*ms*dt*(x1-xs)/(r1s*r1s*r1s) - G*m2*(x1-x2)*dt/(r12*r12*r12);
        vy1 = vy1 - G*ms*dt*(y1-ys)/(r1s*r1s*r1s) - G*m2*(y1-y2)*dt/(r12*r12*r12);

        vx2 = vx2 - G*ms*dt*(x2-xs)/(r2s*r2s*r2s) - G*m1*(x2-x1)*dt/(r12*r12*r12);
        vy2 = vy2 - G*ms*dt*(y2-ys)/(r2s*r2s*r2s) - G*m1*(y2-y1)*dt/(r12*r12*r12);

        vxs = vxs - G*m1*(xs-x1)*dt/(r1s*r1s*r1s) - G*m2*(xs-x2)*dt/(r2s*r2s*r2s);
        vys = vys - G*m1*(ys-y1)*dt/(r1s*r1s*r1s) - G*m2*(ys-y2)*dt/(r2s*r2s*r2s);


        x1 = x1 + vx1*dt;
        y1 = y1 + vy1*dt;

        x2 = x2 + vx2*dt;
        y2 = y2 + vy2*dt;

        xs = xs + vxs*dt;
        ys = ys + vys*dt;

        time += dt;

        output << time << ' ' << x1 << ' ' << y1 << ' ' << x2 << ' ' << y2 << ' ' << xs << ' ' << ys <<endl;
    }

    output.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"initializing the system such that the total angular momentum is 0"* You want the total *linear* momentum to be zero (the keep the system in the same part of the coordinate space). There is no reason *a priori* to expect the total angular momentum to vanish. Hopefully you have just mistyped.

Answer (score 5):

Your problems is that variants Euler is the incorrect method for gravitational systems.  You need to look into [Symplectic Integrators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator).  This will solve the stability issue you are having since this type of integrators hold certain values constant (in this case energy).

Also, as a comment on your code, you should use temporary variables for holding derivates before you update state variables.  As you have it now, updating variables one by one, mixes information from two time steps.  Right now you are updating the velocities explicitly and the positions implicitly.  Unless you have a good reason to do so, it is better to stick to a single method for a problem so you have known stability characteristics.

**Edit:**
As the comments stated, you were using a symplectic integrator, so that is not the issue.  You simply have a couple small typos in your code.

First, in the second term of your update for v2, you used `x2` and `y2` rather than `(x2-xs)` and `(y2-ys)`.  This shouldn't make much difference though since your sun should stay near 0,0.

Your main errors was that in the update for the suns velocity, you multiplied by the product of radii rather than dividing by it.  The four lines are fixed here:

```
    vx2 = vx2 - G*ms*dt*(x2-xs)/(r2s*r2s*r2s) - G*m1*(x2-x1)*dt/(r12*r12*r12);
    vy2 = vy2 - G*ms*dt*(y2-ys)/(r2s*r2s*r2s) - G*m1*(y2-y1)*dt/(r12*r12*r12);

    vxs = vxs - G*m1*(xs-x1)*dt/(r1s*r1s*r1s) - G*m2*(xs-x2)*dt/(r2s*r2s*r2s);
    vys = vys - G*m1*(ys-y1)*dt/(r1s*r1s*r1s) - G*m2*(ys-y2)*dt/(r2s*r2s*r2s);
```

Comment: Hi! The good reason too use the new velocities to update the old position is that I'm using the Euler-Cromer method, that is symplectic! ; )

Comment: Sorry I blanked on that one.  I've converted your code to matlab and will take a closer look into what is going on.

Comment: No problem! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I think ive found your error, please look at the updated answer.

Comment: OMG! So stupid! I was looking at the code for too much time (I should have done a break)... Thank you very much! ; ).

Comment: Not a problem.  I've done the same and it's amazing what a fresh set of eyes will find.

Comment: Despite the corrections, the program still don't work properly... Any idea?

Comment: It what way doesn't work?  I plotted it in matlab when I found those errors, and the earth and jupiter sucessfully orbited the sun for several jupiter years.

Comment: Can you move the discussion to the chat for a while?

Comment: Now does not work because I modified the expression of the angular momentum, because before it was wrong... =S

Comment: Your new code is doing exactly what it is supposed to.  Your system is maintaining 0 angular momentum about its center of gravity.  It just so happens that this causes a net positive y-momentum.  This configuration is unstable.  If you impose 0 y momentum at the start, you get a stable system with the two larger masses completing large orbits around each other.

Comment: Yeah, I misread the hint of the exercise (in English I often confuse momentum and angler momentum). All look great, but the simulation with the mass of Jupiter multiplied by 1000 seems a little bit strange to me... You thin that is right?

Comment: With jupiter 1000 times heavier the energy of the system must be sufficient that it does not form stable orbits.  The simulation isn't wrong, it's just simulating a non-realistic system.

Comment: Ok. It is only that I saw some very strange trajectories for the Earth that I cannot replicate (whit jupiter 1000 times heavier)... But the for the other simulations the program seems good now! Thank you!!! ; )

Answer (score -2):

double G(1.9838e-29); ??

maybe use: G = 6.673e-11

and try something lake this:
q = q*q*q; // one

f = 1/q; g = 2/q; h = 3/q; // two, three, ...

Comment: The value of Newton's gravitational constant depends on the choice of units and the OP is clearly not working is SI base units, but in a system where the length unit is AU.